# Bot framework - Use LUIS in Scorables

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I've read that to handle messages globally, I have to use Scorables and set a score based on the user's input. I am wondering if I can use LUIS to parse the user input and set a score based on LUIS intent score.

Is there any way that I can use LUIS inside my Scorable class?

Or do i have to manually call LUIS and get the response and process myself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call LUIS yourself, pass the message to it and see what it returns. 
You will receive a list of intents with a score back and you typically take the one with the highest score.

LUIS is just an API with one endpoint so you can call it from wherever really, it's actually very easy. Have a look here for more details : https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows

The response from LUIS will give you the intent and the parameters it identified assuming you had any. It's probably a good idea to set a threshold, if the score you get back is not high enough then that means you need to train LUIS more but that's another story. My own threshold is set at 88 anything below that, I don't really like.

If you do it like this you basically eliminate any need to do any processing yourself and you use LUIS for what it's mean to be used, which is understanding the user's query. You can do something with the result after that.

Comment: So when I use LUIS inside scorable, won't it call the LUIS endpoint multiple times? Scorable captures each and every input.If I use LUIS to score the scorable,(1st endpoint call) I can select a scorable and call a dialog. When the dialog is called, since the dialog is a LUIS dialog, it will again call the LUIS to match the LUIS intent inside the LUIS dialog (2nd endpoint call). Am i correct?